# How to clip and fill a canvas using an alpha mask

Tags: android

I have some .png icons that are alpha masks. I need to render them as an drawable image using the Android SDK.

On the iPhone, I use the following to get this result, converting the "image" alpha mask to the 'imageMasked' image using black as a fill:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, thumbWidth, 
    thumbHeight, 8, 4*thumbWidth, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,thumbWidth,thumbHeight);
CGContextClipToMask(context, frame, [image CGImage]);
CGContextFillRect(context, frame);

CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);
```

How do I accomplish the above in Android SDK?

I've started to write the following:

```
Drawable image = myPngImage;

final int width = image.getMinimumWidth();
final int height = image.getMinimumHeight();

Bitmap imageMasked = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
    height, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(iconMasked);
image.draw(canvas); ???
```

I'm not finding how to do the clipping on imageMasked using image.

Comment: i'm probably didn't get the question, but if you assign image with alpha to image view - alpha will be there.

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is convert the alpha bitmap into a clipping region and using that for the fill. Essentially applying an alpha mask. 

Any other takers on an answer?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is something along these lines:

final int width = icon.getMinimumWidth();
final int height = icon.getMinimumHeight();
    
Bitmap iconMasked = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
    height, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(iconMasked);
final Region region = icon.getTransparentRegion();
canvas.clipRegion(region);
canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);

The problem with this approach is my icon is return a null from getTransparentRegion(). Didn't expect that, so I'm still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

```
Drawable icon = An_Icon_That_Is_An_Alpha_Mask;
int width = icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
int height = icon.getIntrinsicHeight();
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
icon.setBounds(new Rect(0,0,width,height));
icon.draw(canvas);
```